# How to make a form mobile friendly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some simple form, that looks good in browser:

[image: Browser screenshots.]

However when I load this page from mobile device, the form looks very small:

[image: Mobile screenshot.]

What is the best way to make this form pretty for mobile-looking, on the full mobile screen? Should I do it with CSS or Bootstrap? Is there some general way to reach it?

Comment: add a meta viewport tag.

Comment: your question would is primarily opinion based and that's off topic on SO. Add some code to make it relevant.

Comment: @ZimSystem The code is trivial, all what I needed was a meta `viewport` tag.

Comment: @neophyte no no, there is a concrete answer on my questions, just to use one meta tag.

Comment: The code IS relevant to identifying the issue as duplicate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add a meta **viewport** tag to make the form fit the cell phone screen.The **viewport** is the user's visible area of a web page. The **viewport** varies with the device, and will be smaller on a mobile phone than on a computer screen.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

[More details on viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Add this meta tag to the head of the page,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

You can also use bootstrap grid layout.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! Btw what do you mean by bootstrap grid layout? Could you drop me the link please.

Comment: Please go through the link                                                             
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/

Answer (score 2):

css scale method

```
div {
-ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
```

find more at : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

you may use the @media min-width and max-width to have more css for every screen..

Comment: you can see a bit of solutions, html- css- js and so.. choose the one you find it better